# Can't drop a view onto another. Am zoomed in. xcode 6.3.2

Tags: xcode, view, drag-and-drop

This should be simple. I have a view controller on the storyboard. I am zoomed in. I try to drag and drop another view controller on top of it and it won't work. I've never had this problem before. I have restarted xcode with no help.

What's my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You wouldn't normally embed view controllers inside of other view controllers. I haven't used it myself so I wouldn't know for sure, but I think a 'Container View' can help you get the desired result.

Comment: Dumb of me, but you made me realize what I was doing. I meant to drag a view on top. Not a view controller.  Very stupid

Comment: That makes way more sense :)